# Hide DIV when text is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two `div` classes, one for login and one for signup. Now, for the login `div`, there's underlined text which asks to Sign Up, and for the signup `div`, there's underlined text which asks to Log In. When these texts are clicked, the respective `div` should have no display and the other `div` should be displayed.

HTML:

```
<div class="login">
        <h2 class="textHead">MedConnect</h2>
        <h2 class="logintxt">Log In to Your Account</h2>
        <input type="text" class="loginemailtxt" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input type="password" class="loginpwdtxt" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button class="loginbtn" type="button" name="button">Log In</button>
        <h5 id="signuptext" style="margin-top: 50px; text-align: center;">Don't have an Account? <u style="cursor: pointer;">Sign Up</u></h5>
        <h6 style="text-align: center;">By clicking "Log In", you log back into your Existing Account</h6>
        <div id="errorMsg">
          <h5 id="loginNoEmail">Please enter your email address</h5>
          <h5 id="loginNoPassword">Please enter your password</h5>
          <h5 id="loginIncorrectCreds">Incorrect Email or Password</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="signup" style="display: none">
        <h2 class="textHead">MedConnect</h2>
        <h2 class="logintxt">Create a New Account</h2>
        <input type="text" class="signupnametxt" name="Name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" class="signupemailtxt" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input type="password" class="signuppwdtxt" name="Password" placeholder="Create Password">
        <button class="signupbtn" type="button" name="Button">Sign Up</button>
        <h5 id="logintext" style="margin-top: 50px; text-align: center;">Already a Member? <u style="cursor: pointer;">Log In</u></h5>
        <h6 style="margin-top: 5px; text-align: center;">By clicking "Sign Up", you agree to our <u style="cursor: pointer;">Terms</u> and <u style="cursor: pointer;">Privacy Policy</u></h6>
        <div id="errorMsg">
          <h5 id="loginNoEmail">Please enter your email address</h5>
          <h5 id="loginNoPassword">Please enter your password</h5>
          <h5 id="loginIncorrectCreds">Incorrect Email or Password</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
```

JavaScript (creating a variable for each element required):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var signuptxt = document.getElementById('signuptext');
var logintxt = document.getElementById('logintext');
var loginDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('login');
var signUpDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('signup');

</script>
```

Comment: I downvoted this because I think this is a homework question that you want someone else to do for you. I'm suspicious that someone who wrote the html and js above doesn't know how to hide / display html elements on click. If you show that you made some effort trying to solve the problem then I'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function showorHide(showDivName, hideDivName) {
      var showDiv = document.getElementsByClassName(showDivName);
      var hideDiv = document.getElementsByClassName(hideDivName);
      hideDiv[0].style.display = 'none'
      showDiv[0].style.display = 'block'
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login" style="display: block">
    <h2 class="textHead">MedConnect</h2>
    <h2 class="logintxt">Log In to Your Account</h2>
    <input type="text" class="loginemailtxt" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="password" class="loginpwdtxt" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button class="loginbtn" type="button" name="button">Log In</button>
    <h5 id="signuptext" style="margin-top: 50px; text-align: center;">Don't have an Account? <u
        onclick="showorHide('signup','login')" style="cursor: pointer;">Sign Up</u></h5>
    <h6 style="text-align: center;">By clicking "Log In", you log back into your Existing Account</h6>
    <div id="errorMsg">
      <h5 id="loginNoEmail">Please enter your email address</h5>
      <h5 id="loginNoPassword">Please enter your password</h5>
      <h5 id="loginIncorrectCreds">Incorrect Email or Password</h5>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="signup" style="display: none">
    <h2 class="textHead">MedConnect</h2>
    <h2 class="logintxt">Create a New Account</h2>
    <input type="text" class="signupnametxt" name="Name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" class="signupemailtxt" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="password" class="signuppwdtxt" name="Password" placeholder="Create Password">
    <button class="signupbtn" type="button" name="Button">Sign Up</button>
    <h5 id="logintext" style="margin-top: 50px; text-align: center;">Already a Member? <u
        onclick="showorHide('login','signup')" style="cursor: pointer;">Log In</u></h5>
    <h6 style="margin-top: 5px; text-align: center;">By clicking "Sign Up", you agree to our <u
        style="cursor: pointer;">Terms</u> and <u style="cursor: pointer;">Privacy Policy</u></h6>
    <div id="errorMsg">
      <h5 id="loginNoEmail">Please enter your email address</h5>
      <h5 id="loginNoPassword">Please enter your password</h5>
      <h5 id="loginIncorrectCreds">Incorrect Email or Password</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```